# Render text with image in React Native

Tags: react-native

How to render a paragraph with image at right,
the screen design should be similar to the screenshot[image]

Comment: i have found issues related to the same [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4563), any solution for this other than rendering WebView

Answer (score 0):

React Native does not support text justification in the way you want. You could somewhat emulate this effect for one paragraph at a time by rendering each paragraph in its own `Text` component, then rendering the following for paragraphs that have accompanying images:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor......</Text>
  <Image source={require('./path/to/image.png')} />
</View>
```

You'll probably want to add some left padding to the image component so the text doesn't run right up against it.

Comment: but the text wont wrap below the image and text will be growing ,is it possibe to calculate how much text the frame will accomodate (for eg height:100,width:200 frame)? then ican make new text component below the view with image and text.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not yet possible with RN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
let pic = {
  uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
};

return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 360, height: 110}}/>
    <Text>React Application Works fine!</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: what will be the style={styles.container} ? add the container style or better add inline.